# Who is this great man?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, history

> A man of great power,
>   beloved of a nation,
>   leader of an army,
>   exalted in his station.
>   When he marched to battle,
>   all his might assembled,
>   soldiers, once formidable,
>   in sight of him, they trembled.

Comment: Obviously it's Donald Trump.

Comment: When did he march to battle?  And no, political debates and elections are not battles.

Comment: @cbmeeks [Ford Prefect? Is that you?](http://www.anvari.org/fortune/Miscellaneous_Collections/278495_they-dont-have-sarcasm-on-betelgeuse-and-ford-prefect-often-failed-to-notice-it-unless-he-was-concentrating.html)

Comment: @cbmeeks "political debates and elections are not battles": with metaphor, all things are possible.

Comment: Oh my people....yes, I understand sarcasm.  Doesn't appear you did.  lol

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is:

> Napoleon Bonaparte.

Mostly because:

> The initial letters of each line start the classic palindrome "Able was I ere I saw Elba."

And also:

A man of great power, ..., exalted in his station.

> Emperor of France.

Leader of an army.

> Best known as a military genius.

As for the last four lines:

> Maybe that's referring to the incident near the beginning of the Hundred Days, with the troops sent to arrest him?  Napoleon reportedly ripped open his coat and said: "If any of you will shoot his Emperor, here I am."  Then the troops instead defected to his side.  (Also could illustrate the "beloved of a nation" line.)

Comment: Damn, just beat me to it.

Comment: Beat me to it! Then @gnovice beat me to saying "Beat me to it"!

Comment: Beat me to it by saying "Beat me it to it" by saying... "beat me to it"! ;P

Comment: Ah, this was clearly too easy! That was so fast I can't even accept the answer yet. There are no more essential details, it's just the bit in your "mostly because" section that matter.

Comment: So *that's* where they stole the Dr Who scene from (in *Hell Bent*, IIRC).